# Verify my proof that eigenvalues of a unitary matrix have absolute value 1

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

Show that eigenvalues of a unitary matrix have absolute value 1.

Proof below.  Please verify, critique, or improve.  *Note: Many proofs are available; this question is to verify this proof*.

---

Notation: $M^H$ is the conjugate transpose of $M$.

Let $Q^HQ = I, Qx = \lambda x, x \neq 0$.  Then $$\begin{align}
\lambda \bar \lambda x^Hx &= (\lambda x)^H(\lambda x) \quad \text{(by linearity)} \\
&= (Qx)^H(Qx) \\
&= x^HQ^HQx \\
& = x^Hx.
\end{align}$$

Since $x \neq 0$, then $x^Hx \neq 0$, and $\lambda \bar \lambda  = 1$, so $|\lambda| = 1$.

Comment: Well, you somehow showed more that it has to be $1,-1$. Apparently, you missed conjugation...

Comment: @Salcio Thanks, should be fixed, please take a look.

Comment: This is the standard proof. Verify it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the argument you are using is standard. Minor details:

- you are missing the absolute value bars at the start, it should be $|\lambda|^2$;
- I wouldn't say that the first equality is due to "linearity", rather you are using the compatibility of the product of matrices with that of numbers, and that $(\lambda x)^H=\overline\lambda\,x^H$;
- instead of assuming that $x\ne0$ you can assume that $x^Hx=1$ (just replace $x$ with $x/\|x\|$) and the argument is marginally simpler.

Comment: Thanks.  I edited it to fix point #1 - is that correct? Re point #2, can you elaborate? To me, linearity is what allows moving the $\lambda$ inside the dot product.

Comment: You are still writing $\lambda^2$ instead of $|\lambda|^2$. As for linearity, fair enough if you refer to the linearity of the inner product, though the proper word would be sesquilinearity. When you write $x^Hy$ instead of one of the common notations for the inner product like $\langle x,y\rangle$ or $(x,y)$ or $(x|y)$, it looks more like a product of matrices (which it is) rather than a sesquilinear function.

Comment: I see, thanks.  Revised again, please take a look now.  What is "compatibility of the product of matrices with that of numbers"?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. What I mean is that if $a,b$ are numbers and $A,B$ are matrices, $(ab)AB=(aA)(bB)$. Don't know if there is a specific name for that.